# why I can not in folder static inside app for project django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-static

I can't get access to the STATIC folder for my Django project.

Here's my project structure.

```
-myproject
--core
  --settings.py
--myapp
  --static
--------myapp
       ---- js
       ---- css
--templates
--static
```

In **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), 
]
```

print STATICFILES_DIRS:

```
['/media/my_pc/Apps/my_project/static']
```

In my main **urls.py**, I use this:

```
 if settings.DEBUG:
        from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
        urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Now, when I try to call the static .js file, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try defining your STATIC_ROOT right below STATIC_URL in settings.py. Something like this: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`.

Comment: I tried that و don't work ..

Comment: Ok! Maybe then try changing your method of adding the static files to urlpatterns. Something like this: `from django.conf import settings`
`from django.conf.urls.static import static`
`urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution. The problem was the way I was called to the block
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock javascripts %}
it was name error in file base.html

Comment: I will not delete the question perhaps someone will benefit from that

Comment: Awesome!  In that case, you should post an answer to your own question. Make sure to go into detail about what the problem/solution was.

Answer (score 1):

## error blook:

this Error on call base.html foces to the blook javaScript
in base.html

```
..
{%block javascript%}
{%endblock javascript%}
```

in my_use_htm.html

```
{%block javaScript%}
{%endblock javaScript%}
```

foces the name blook